# TouchableOpacity onPress() not working with react-native-modal

Tags: react-native

I am trying to get TouchableOpacity working with react-native-modal. When I press the button, nothing happens.

Here is my code, on pressing the button, there is no press animation and no alert appears:

```js
<Modal
  isVisible={this.state.modalVisible}
  onBackdropPress={() => this.setState({ modalVisible: false })}
  deviceWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width}
  deviceHeight={Dimensions.get('window').height}
  backdropColor={'rgba(29, 36, 40, 0.5)'}>
  <View style={styles.modal}>
    <Text style={styles.modalTitle}>Test modal</Text>
    <View style={modalButtons}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert('hello!')}><Text style={styles.modalButton}>Test</Text></TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ modalVisible: false })}><Text style={styles.modalButton}>Close</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </View>
</Modal>
```

I am importing TouchableOpacity from react-native, not react-native-gesture-handler (one solution mentioned this; all it did for me was prevent the buttons from being invisible).

EDIT: I've narrowed it down to the View around the buttons. When I remove this the following style, it works:

```js
  modalButtons: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginBottom: 30,
  },
```

Is there a way to keep this flex working? I would like for the buttons to display side by side.

Comment: Can you try wrapping TouchableOpacity by `<React.Fragment>` or `<View>`?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, it didn't seem to work @DivyeShah

Comment: Does removing margin make any difference? Try using TouchableWithoutFeedback to check if it makes any difference?

Comment: Using TouchableWithoutFeedback fixed the issue, but it doesn't show any text.

Comment: Wrapping the TouchableOpacity by TouchableWithoutFeedback shows text but it goes back to not responding to any input.

Comment: Okay, I needed to add "flex: 1" to the modal style, which fixed the issues. However, now the modal takes up the full height of the screen, rather than just being tall as needed.

Comment: I fixed with position: 'absolute'

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I had the same problem. Check that your `TouchableOpacity` is imported from the `"react-native"` module and not from anything else. (Mine was in `react-native-gesture-handler`.)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much!